# Why is Edit Configuration Button Disabled in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-6

I have a WCF Web Service hosted in IIS6 and it targets the .NET 4.0 framework. When I right click on the web app in IIS and choose properties > ASP.NET, the Edit Configuration button is grayed out.

If I change the framework to 2.0, it becomes enabled. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you by chance install .NET 4 before installing IIS? You might try running

```
aspnet_regiis -r
```

or

```
aspnet_regiis -iru
```

Check the documentation with `/?` to figure out which one is appropriate for your scenario. ALso make sure you're running the .NET 4 version of aspnet_regiis.